# Unable to get around with ng-controller

Tags: json, angularjs

I am a beginner with AngularJS trying to build a template using it.

My `points.html` page is like this:

```
          <form ng-app="stdapp"  ng-submit="save()" ng-controller="SubmissionController">

                <div class="select">
                    <label> Select Student </label>
                    <select ng-options="student.name for student in students" ng-model="student"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label ng-repeat="behavior in behaviors">
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="behavior"> {{behavior.name}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Mark</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and my `points.js` looks like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('stdapp', []);
app.controller('SubmissionController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.save = function() {
        console.log($scope.student);
        console.log($scope.behavior);
};

$http.get("/manager/api/std/useraccount/").success(function(response) {
    $scope.students = response.objects;
}).error(function() {
    alert("An Unexpected error occured");
});

$http.get("/manager/api/std/behavior/").success(function(response) {
    $scope.behaviors = response.objects;
}).error(function() {
    alert("An Unexpected error occured");
});
});
```

These APIs are working fine and I get data from server in json format. This is the response for the first API GET call :-

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 3}, 
    "objects": [
        {"age": 12, "clas": 5, "id": "559f55347abead2404a61563", "name": "harish", "resource_uri": "/manager/api/std/useraccount/559f55347abead2404a61563/", "studentid": 1}, 
        {"age": 13, "clas": 5, "id": "559f555a7abead2404a61564", "name": "zaya", "resource_uri": "/manager/api/std/useraccount/559f555a7abead2404a61564/", "studentid": 2}, 
        {"age": 11, "clas": 5, "id": "559f556f7abead2404a61565", "name": "harsha", "resource_uri": "/manager/api/std/useraccount/559f556f7abead2404a61565/", "studentid": 3}
    ]
}
```

and the json reply for second get is

```
{
"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 3}, 
"objects": [
    {"id": "559f560b7abead2404a61566", "name": "Doing Homework", "points": 3, "resource_uri": "/manager/api/std/behavior/559f560b7abead2404a61566/"}, 
    {"id": "559f56227abead2404a61567", "name": "Disrrupting Class", "points": -2, "resource_uri": "/manager/api/std/behavior/559f56227abead2404a61567/"},         
    {"id": "559f56337abead2404a61568", "name": "Helping", "points": 5, "resource_uri": "/manager/api/std/behavior/559f56337abead2404a61568/"}]}
```

But still I'm not able to properly render the received object array in my template.

I wrote a form as in the end I want to submit the selected data, so I also want to know how can I write a submit `($http.post())` in this case.

Can someone please help me, I've tried google but the examples I got were either very high level or very basic.

Comment: Tried using `$scope.$apply()` after the `get`?

Comment: no and what does it do

Comment: `apply` essentially updated the model data across the view. On async functions you may need this behaviour. Should work in your case

Comment: It has nothing to do with `$apply` and should not be used here at all. Your problem is different.

Comment: tried it but still data is not rendred in template.

Answer (score 1):

Template won't render unless you add `ngModel` directive. This is required attributed because binding data to form controls makes no sense without mechanism to get data back for further processing (submission).

Your HTML should be something like this:

```
    <div class="select" ng-controller="PointspageController">
        <label> Select Student </label>
        <select ng-options="student.name for student in students" ng-model="student.name"></select>
    </div>
```

However this is just one problem. You need to make sure you do next things:

1. Put your HTML into common controller like `ng-controller="SubmissionController"` where you would define function to be used as submit handler:

   ```
   app.controller('SubmissionController', function($scope) {
       $scope.save = function() {
           console.log($scope.student);
       };
   });
   ```
2. Add ngSubmit directive on the form:

   ```
   <form ng-app="stdapp" ng-submit="save()" ng-controller="SubmissionController">
       <!-- ... -->
   </form>
   ```

Comment: So i did what you said and it worked in the case of Points page controller. but behaviorcontroller part is still not working as i don't understand why ng repeat is not printining lable text. in this case json reply have three objects so three checkbox are shown but no lable text. can you help

Comment: so i have edited the question and added the json response for second api also but still i'am not getting the lable text for the checkboxes.